# Search by Date range in Elastic search malformed query

Tags: php, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to integrate search by date range with PHP and elastic search

```
$params1 = [
'index' => 'joborders',
'type' => 'joborder',
'from' =>0,
'size' => 50,


     'body' => [

     'query' => [
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => $wildCardString,
                'fields' => ['description'],

                ]
        ]
    ]
];

$filter_date=array();
$filter_date['range']['datecreatedsort']['gte']='2015-11-27';
$filter_date['range']['datecreatedsort']['lte']='2017-11-27';
$params1['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']=$filter_date;
$params1['body']['sort']['datecreatedsort']['order'] = 'desc';

   try {
     $results = $client->search($params1);
     //print_r($results);
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
$last = $client->transport->getLastConnection()->getLastRequestInfo();
$last['results']['error'] = [];
print_r($last);
}
```

When I am running above query I am getting following error

> [query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found
>   [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":78},"status":400}
>
> datecreatedsort filed mapping is date type is date and value in
>   elastic search db is "datecreatedsort":"2016-05-30T09:39:40.000Z"

please help where is the issue in elastic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Got the solution its working fine

```
$params1 = [
'index' => 'joborders',
'type' => 'joborder',
'body' => [
    'query' => [
        'bool' => [
            'filter' => [
                'range' => [ 'date_modified' => ['gt'=>$duration,'lt'=>$today,'boost'=> '2.0'] ]
            ],
            'must' => [
                'match' => [ 'description' => $wildCardString ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
 ]
];
```

Thanks guys for help.

Answer (score 2):

It's the native `elasticsearch` request.

In `PHP` you need to create array query with the same structure.

```
GET /joborders/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "created_at": {
              "gte": "2017-11-22 13:49:00",
               "lte": "2017-11-22 23:50:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

PS You need to pass date ranges in the same format as `datecreatedsort` in db ("2016-05-30T09:39:40.000Z")

Comment: hi for only range  this query is right but i have to use wildcard string too. can you suggest how to put it

Comment: @VipinS, could you please give me an example what exactly do you need?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "description",
            "query": $wildCardString
          }

        },
        "filter": {
          "range": {
            "datecreatedsort": {
              "gte": '2015-11-27',
              "lte": '2017-11-27'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }  
}
```

your code for the query will look something like this:

```
$query=array(
  'filtered'=>array(
      'query' => array(
            'query_string' => [
                'query' => $wildCardString,
                'fields' => ['description'],
                ]
       ),
       'filter'=>$filter_date  
  )
);
```

Comment: its showing {"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in

Comment: can you help why this issue comes